# How to get the value of a text box in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, textbox, dialog

Question I have simple textbox with an ID called IDC_FILE_NUMBER_EDIT how can I get the value of this text box when I click a button. below is my code any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my button when it gets clicked I want to get the text or value from

```
void CJunkView::OnCadkeyButton() 

{  
    //Get text in IDC_FILE_NUMBER_EDIT text box. 

    std::string filenum = IDC_FILE_NUMBER_EDIT->Text;
    //For some reason I cant use this I get this error C2227: left of   '->Text' must point to class/struct/union

}
```

Comment: What framework are you using?  MFC?  WTL?  What?

Comment: I'm assuming MFC. Correct me if wrong.

Comment: @Snowman288 Please tell me whether you are using unicode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for MBCS.

```
CString tempS;
GetDlgItem(IDC_FILE_NUMBER_EDIT)->GetWindowText(tempS);
CT2CA pszConvertedAnsiString (tempS);
std::string strStd (pszConvertedAnsiString);
```

This should work for Unicode with minimal modifications if at all necessary

```
CString tempS;
GetDlgItem(IDC_FILE_NUMBER_EDIT)->GetWindowText(tempS);
std::string s((LPCTSTR)tempS);
```

To check whether you are using Unicode or MBCS, go to `Project Properties -> General -> Character Set`